# Webview keeps old Url on every call

Tags: android, webview

I'm using a C2Dm service to push notifications to my app. I have an activity which consists only of some corporate design elements and the webview.

When I start my app for the first time and push a url to the device the user gets an notification in the notification bar. If he clicks on the notification I create a PendingIntent to start the webview-activity.

Till here, everything is fine. But the App keeps opening the first URL it got via C2DM message and never shows a new url. The url itself is passed via bundle extra.

So here's the code to create the pending intent for the notification:

```
    Intent intent = WebviewActivity.asIntent(context, getUrlWithAttachedAccesskey(notification.getUrl()), new Bundle()); // just a static method to wrap the bundle correctly
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.appiconmenu, message, System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, pIntent);
    notificationMan.notify(getNextNotificationId(), notification);
```

On the WebviewActivity site the code looks like that:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if(extras != null) {
        String url = intent.getExtras().getString(DESTINATION_URL);     
        Log.i(TAG, "Loading url: " + url);
        wbVwBrowser.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Is there something wrong with my intent? Do I have to call it differently? Is it the webview?

**UPDATE:**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(sender, WebviewActivity.class);      
    extras.putString(DESTINATION_URL, destUrl);
    intent.putExtras(extras);

    return intent;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this flag :

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

instead of:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Comment: try to inject url with bundle without static wrapping method!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

You have to override onNewIntent() in your Activity to access the PendingIntents Bundle that contains the new URL. getIntent() will always return the original Intent that started the Activity.

Comment: onNewIntent never gets called.

Comment: "This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent)."

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
  Notification notification = new I use this code: 
Notification(R.drawable.appiconmenu, message, System.currentTimeMillis());
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
But onNewIntent still doesn't get called.